# &hearts; and &diams; in the HTML show as black on Android even though the color is set as red in the CSS

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, meteor

I am developing a card game in HTML, JS and CSS using the Meteor platform. I am using `&hearts;` for the hearts suit and `&diams;` for the dimonds suit. The color is set to red using `color: #FF0000;` in CSS. The font-family is set with `font-family: 'Times', serif;`. On a desktop PC, Mac or iPhone these show up as red icons, but on an Android using Chrome they show up as black. However, the rank is still displayed as red which leads me to believe this is specific to the icons themselves.

Before displaying the suit string I run the code through the SafeString function in Spacebar.

```
suitString: function(suit) {
    var suits = {'H': '&hearts;', 'S':'&spades;', 'D':'&diams;', 'C':'&clubs;'}

    return Spacebars.SafeString(suits[suit]);
  }
```

I imagine it has something to do with the font that is used to render the icons on Android, but I have been unable to figure out exactly why this is happening. Or it could be something specific to the SafeString function.

Can anyone enlighten me and is there a way to ensure the color on all devices without using images for the suits?

Thanks!

Comment: add specific code in your post where the problem is.

Comment: Not reproduceable. Tested in Chrome 39, Android 4.1.

Comment: @sufiyan There is nothing more specific to add than what has already been described. As stated I believe this has to do with how the font is rendered.

Comment: @sufiyan I was wrong. I added a code block that is specific to the Spacebars engine.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am not sure exactly what device or Chrome version this was done on, but I know it was with Chrome on an Android. The issue was reported by someone who tested the game, but the user was could not state the Android version and I am not in a position to get that information now. I posted this question because I figured this should be something that has been solved before, but my searching skill could not find an answer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an Android 5.0.x font rendering bug. It happens on web pages and within applications. So far I've only seen it on Android 5.0.1

I can't reproduce it on android 5.1.0 and 4.2.x

I really drove me mad. At first I though html tables wouldn't accept color.

Here is my test page: http://ibob.github.io/tests/html/

If you open it on an Android 5.0.1 device, the solid red suits won't be colored.

The empty suits look bad, so I guess going with images is the only sensible solution.

EDIT:

Actually after more digging, this seems to be a TouchWiz issue (ie Samsung only).

In their TouchWiz updates after 5.0.1, Samsung changed the font rendering of solid suit colors to something like emoji - immune to coloring. Apparently, it can't be reproduced on non-Samsung devices but it's reproducible on every one with an Android version bigger than 5.0.0.

Note that HTC have done a similar thing, but kept the colors of solid suit colors. However with modern HTC devices you can't draw spades or clubs with a color other than black, and hearts and diamonds with a color other than red.

Other device brands with their custom android mods may have similar issues.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for a delayed response to this. It has been a really long time since I worked on this project. I have not been able to verify your solution, but I am accepting it as it seems plausible. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Just encountered this problem, too. 
Testing on a Samsung-Note-3 (Android 5.1.1), turns out the suit-symbols are all black when I load your testpage in Chrome or the preinstalled "Internet" browser.
However, in Firefox installed on Android, it is rendered with correct colors (same as on windows pc).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when using ♥ (black heart suit, as described in http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp)

In PC, you can change the color with the css color attribute. However, in android, it shows in black regardless the color you specify.

I suspect that is a problem of the android browser rendering that black heart suit with that black icon.

I used ♡ instead (white empty heart) which takes css color attribute not only for PC but also for android browser.
Alternatively, an image with the desired color or an svg built in the code could use any css color.